# matplotlib: autofmt_xdate doesn't work for multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the autofmt_xdate() to get better looking x-axis (in date) like below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12, 5))
ax[0].plot(my_df[['my_time']], my_df[['field_A']])
ax[0].set_xlable('time')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

This works fine. However, if I do two rows like below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(12, 5))
ax[0][0].plot(my_df[['my_time']], my_df[['field_A']])
ax[0][0].set_xlable('time')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Then the labels and ticks of ax[0][0] x-axis disappeared. Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong here. What you see is the expected behaviour of [`fig.autofmt_xdate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate).

As the documentation says,

> The ticklabels are often long, and it helps to rotate them on the bottom subplot and **turn them off on other subplots**, as well as turn off xlabels.